# allocate objects on the stack (with copies) or heap (with pointers)

Tags: c++

I have some basic questions about using the stack vs the heap. There's a bunch of answers out there, but I'm not sure how to relate it to the following.

I think it's easier to explain by way of example...

Is it "better" to do

```
struct Widget3 {
    Widget3(std::shared_ptr<Widget1> widget1, std::shared_ptr<Widget2> widget2)
    : _widget1(std::move(widget1))
    , _widget2(std::move(widget2))
    {
    }

    void doSomething()
    {
        std::cout << _widget1.hello() << _widget2.hello();
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Widget1> _widget1;
    std::shared_ptr<Widget2> _widget2;
};
```

or this

```
struct Widget3 {
    Widget3(const Widget1 & widget1, const Widget2 & widget2)
    : _widget1(widget1)
    , _widget2(widget2)
    {
    }

    void doSomething()
    {
        std::cout << _widget1->hello() << _widget2->hello();
    }
private:
    Widget1 _widget1;
    Widget2 _widget2;
};
```

The second example causes us to copy `Widget1` and `Widget2`, but lets say we create all these objects once at the beginning of the program and don't care about the cost (performance and memory) of copying the objects.

Is it somehow faster to use the second example, where `_widget1` and `_widget2` are on the stack?

Comment: Someone's misinformed you as to what "stack" and "heap" mean, alas.

Comment: Please enlighten me. Isn't example1 Widget1 and Widget2 allocated on the heap, and example2 Widget1 and Widget2 allocated on the stack? In the example1 only one instance of Widget1 and Widget2 exist. In example2 Widget1 and Widget2 exist in two places (at least).

Comment: Both could be on the heap (consider `new Widget3`). Stop talking about storage locations and talk about storage _durations_. Static, automatic and dynamic storage duration.

Answer (score 0):

Your second way is better because there is no chance of memory leaks, in case you chose not to use a smart pointer.

There is no guarantee that it will all be done on the stack, though.

What if I wrote:

```
Widget1 widget1;
Widget2 widget2;
Widget3 *widget3 = new Widget3(widget1, widget2);

int main(){
    // do something with 'widget3'
    delete widget3;
}
```

What about then?

You should prefer not using pointers whenever possible, it's just safer. But if there will be multiple handles to your data and you can't pass by reference (for whatever crazy reason) then by all means, go with example 1.

It's all about which method is better in the situation. No method will **always** be better than another.

Answer (score 0):

First thing first, those two Widget3 implementations are not the same. The first implementaiton of Widget3 with shared_ptr will simply move pointers( will not copy Widget1 or Widget2 ). However, the second implementation will copy Widget1 and Widget2 into member variable.

Here is the proof:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

namespace
{
    std::ostream& os = std::cout;
}

struct Widget1
{
    Widget1()
    {
        os << __FUNCSIG__ << std::endl;
    }
    Widget1( const Widget1& rhs )
    {
        os << __FUNCSIG__ << std::endl;
    }
    Widget1( Widget1&& rhs )
    {
        os << __FUNCSIG__ << std::endl; 
    }
};

struct Widget2
{
    Widget2()
    {
        os << __FUNCSIG__ << std::endl;
    }
    Widget2( const Widget2& rhs )
    {
        os << __FUNCSIG__ << std::endl;
    }
    Widget2( Widget2&& rhs )
    {
        os << __FUNCSIG__ << std::endl;
    }
};

struct Widget3_1 {
    Widget3_1(std::shared_ptr<Widget1> widget1, std::shared_ptr<Widget2> widget2)
    : _widget1(std::move(widget1))
    , _widget2(std::move(widget2))
    {
    }
private:
    std::shared_ptr<Widget1> _widget1;
    std::shared_ptr<Widget2> _widget2;
};


struct Widget3_2 {
    Widget3_2(const Widget1 & widget1, const Widget2 & widget2)
    : _widget1(widget1)
    , _widget2(widget2)
    {
    }
private:
    Widget1 _widget1;
    Widget2 _widget2;
};


int main()
{
    const int repeatCount = 1;
    {
        os << " Widget3_1 : " << std::endl;
        std::shared_ptr<Widget1> widget1( new Widget1 );
        std::shared_ptr<Widget2> widget2( new Widget2 );

        Widget3_1(widget1, widget2);
    }
    {
        os << " Widget3_2 : " << std::endl;
        Widget1 widget1;
        Widget2 widget2;

        Widget3_2(widget1, widget2);
    }

} // int main
```

output:

```
 Widget3_1 :
__thiscall Widget1::Widget1(void)
__thiscall Widget2::Widget2(void)
 Widget3_2 :
__thiscall Widget1::Widget1(void)
__thiscall Widget2::Widget2(void)
__thiscall Widget1::Widget1(const struct Widget1 &)
__thiscall Widget2::Widget2(const struct Widget2 &)
```

Not only you have other things to worry about, I don't think there will be any difference between them. The difference may grow as the project grows big, but there is no way other than testing to prove what is exactly going on. Just to convince you, let's give you some test result. This was tested on VisualC, windows 8.1

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <memory>
#include <intrin.h>

namespace
{
    std::ostream& os = std::cout;
    typedef decltype(__rdtsc()) ClockType;
    ClockType clock;

    void MeasureBegin()
    {
        clock = __rdtsc();
    }

    ClockType MeasureEnd()
    {
        return __rdtsc() - clock;
    }
}

struct Widget1
{
    Widget1()
        : a(0),b(1),c(2),d(3)
    {
    }
    int a,b,c,d;
};

struct Widget2
{
    Widget2()
        :j ("Hello, World")
    {
    }
    std::string j;
};

struct Widget3 {
    Widget3(const Widget1 & widget1, const Widget2 & widget2)
    : _widget1(widget1)
    , _widget2(widget2)
    {
    }
private:
    Widget1 _widget1;
    Widget2 _widget2;
};

int main()
{
    const int testCount = 10;
    const int repeatCount = 100000;
    ClockType c = 0;

    for( int j = 0; j < testCount; ++j )
    {
        Widget1 widget1;
        Widget2 widget2;

        MeasureBegin();
        for (int i = 0; i < repeatCount; ++i)
        {
            Widget3(widget1, widget2);
        }
        c = MeasureEnd();
        std::cout << " 1 : " << c << std::endl;

        Widget1* pwidget1 = new Widget1();
        Widget2* pwidget2 = new Widget2();

        MeasureBegin();
        for (int i = 0; i < repeatCount; ++i)
        {
            Widget3(*pwidget1, *pwidget2);
        }
        c = MeasureEnd();
        std::cout << " 2 : " <<  c << std::endl;

        delete pwidget1;
        delete pwidget2;
    }
} // int main
```

output:

```
1 : 5030133
2 : 5726116
1 : 4898262
2 : 5915359
1 : 4805982
2 : 4988638
1 : 4758595
2 : 5065566
1 : 5470122
2 : 5312685
1 : 5133652
2 : 5753500
1 : 5475479
2 : 5196111
1 : 5153481
2 : 5678220
1 : 4790526
2 : 4820254
1 : 4836252
2 : 5231158
```

No difference.